# Building a module should build dependency modules as well in maven

Tags: maven

In my project i have multiple modules. And one module can have other modules as dependencies. And each modules were having their own pom.xml which contains the dependency details. We have the overall parent pom.xml which will run build of all the packages. And individual module pom.xml will build the respective module.

My requirement is to build the dependency modules before while running the individual package.

For instance:
If my project holds the packages A,B,C,D,E

If module A has the dependencies B and C, on running the module A build it should build module B,C first then it should build the Package A.

I need to achieve this in maven. Please assist me on this. Is there any maven plugin available to achieve this?

Note: I don want to run the parent pom.xml since it will run all the modules.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `mvn -pl :a -am` from the root folder (the same directory where your parent pom is located). This will build the project list "a" (if `a` is your artifactId) and its dependencies

Comment: You can find this information here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html